# Calculate mangled name of C++ template function

Tags: c++, c++11

Let's say I have a C++ template function.

```
template <class T>
int foo(T& t) {
...
}
```

How can I calculate programmatically (not by using nm) the mangled name of a function?

Note, I am not interested in demangling. I am already familiar with the cxxabi header file that does the demangling.

Comment: You want to know how to get the compiler specified mangled name of a templated function but `not by using nm` (which I'm assuming to mean name mangling) .. correct?

Comment: There's no standard way. In fact, there's no fundamental need for name mangling. Name mangling is a hack for linkers which expect a function to be uniquely defined by a single `char[N]`.

Answer (score 5):

It's possible to do it with `typeid`; the trick is to encode a pointer to the function into a type name by creating a type with a non-type template parameter whose value is the function pointer.  For example:

```
template <class T> int foo(T&);
template <auto> struct IntegralConstant {};
std::cout << typeid(IntegralConstant<foo<int>>).name() << '\n';
```

This outputs `16IntegralConstantIXadL_Z3fooIiEiRT_EEE`, which when piped through `c++filt -t` gives `IntegralConstant<&(int foo<int>(int&))>`. The tricky bit is to isolate the symbol `_Z3fooIiEiRT_` (demangling to `int foo<int>(int&)`) from the full type name; this can be done by comparing the mangled type name to the equivalent when `0` is passed in place of the function pointer:

```
template <auto> struct IntegralConstant {};
template <auto& u> std::string mangledSymbolName() {
    std::string null = typeid(IntegralConstant<0>).name();
    std::string symbol = typeid(IntegralConstant<u>).name();
    return symbol.substr(null.size() - 1, symbol.size() - null.size() - 2);
}
```

Example: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/P3eaaYhv6

The magic constants `1` and `2` are dependent on the encodings in the C++ ABI of `0`, pointers to external symbols, and class templates; they'll also require adjustment if `IntegralConstant` is placed in a namespace.

Comment: This method is indeed useful for hacky "by-hand" scenarios, but not always reliable depending on what you want to do. See Scott Meyer's _Effective Modern C++_, item 4 "Know how to view deduced types" for counter examples on all compilers, as well as an explanation: *"Sadly, the results of `std::type_info::name` are not reliable. [...] they're essentially* required *to be incorrect, because the specification for `std::type_info::name` mandates that the type be treated as if it had been passed to a template function as a by-value parameter."*

Comment: @AnthonyD973 can you give an example that doesn't work with my technique?

Comment: Sure! The example given is `template <class T> void f(const T& param) { std::cout << "T    = " << typeid(T).name() << '\n'; std::cout << "param= " << typeid(param).name() << '\n';
}`. Call `f` with an object of some class `Widget`. While `T` is of type `Widget` and `param` of type `const Widget&`, both outputs show `6Widget` on my GCC 9.4.0, as if they were both of type `Widget`.

Comment: @AnthonyD973 I'm having trouble seeing how that's relevant to this answer.

Comment: @AnthonyD973 my function returns `_Z1fI6WidgetEvRKT_` for that example, which demangles to `void f<Widget>(Widget const&)`. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/a3aWe79Ph

Comment: Yeah, I suppose that "failing" scenario doesn't apply to _functions_, which is what the OP was asking, so I guess this answer is correct nonetheless. However, it does apply to other expressions such as function _parameters_, so you can't always use `typeid().name()` blindly.

Answer (score -1):

You could try getting the callstack and getting the function name from there like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

#include <execinfo.h>

std::string GetMangledSymbol(const std::string& str)
{
    static const std::regex regex(R"((\([a-zA-Z0-9_+]*\)))");

    std::smatch matches;
    std::regex_search( str, matches, regex );

    if( ! matches.empty() )
    {
        auto symbolName = matches[1].str().substr(1);
        auto pos = symbolName.find_first_of('+');

        if( pos == std::string::npos)
            return symbolName;

        symbolName.erase( pos );

        return symbolName;
    }

    return {};
}

void printCurrentFunction()
{
    void* array[50] = { nullptr };
    char** strings = nullptr;

    size_t size = backtrace(array, 50);
    strings = backtrace_symbols(array, size);

    std::cout << GetMangledSymbol(strings[1]) << std::endl;

    free(strings);
}

template <class T>
int foo(T&) {
    printCurrentFunction();

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int i = 2;
    foo(i);

    std::string k;
    foo(k);
}
```

Tested on linux with gcc (needs -rdynamic flag).

[**Live**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/2ZDmDLjGZoBaBoHU)